# app delegate leak problem

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I do an analyze in xcode, I get this memory leak on the navController in my appdelegate.m.

The app runs fine, but I just can't get this warning to go away.  Can anyone help?  Is this ok?

Really appreciate anyone help.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    // create window and set up view controller
    [window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    navController.topViewController.title = SHKLocalizedString(@"Quick Lomo Pro");
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
    navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [navController setToolbarHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never releasing the "UINavigationController" after you call the init.

You should store a pointer to the navigation controller and release it in you appdelegate dealloc method.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

      UINavigationController *navController;
 }

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
     ...
}

-(void) dealloc {

    [navController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.  pointer to the navigation controller?  Don't quite get that...can you be more specific?  Or some example code would definitely help.

Comment: just edited the answer with a piece of code... hope it helps :)